# Visual C++ inconsistent narrowing conversion warnings

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, the compiler (Visual C++ 14.0) warns about narrowing conversions (at warning level 4). This is a good feature, but it does not seem to be consistently applied.

For example, in the following code:

```
short bar(short s) {
  return s * 2;
}

short foo(short s) {
  int i = s * s;
  return i; // warning C4242
}

short baz(short s) {
  s *= 2;
  return s;
}
```

All three functions should have the same effect (calculate the multiplication in integer precision, then narrow-cast the result back to short), but a warning is only emitted for foo: warning C4242: 'return': conversion from 'int' to 'short', possible loss of data.

Is this an inconsistency in the compiler, or a misunderstanding on my part? Is there a way that I can get more warnings?

Comment: Multiplying by 2 doesn't result in an int, it's still a short, so no conversion. The only conversion that happens is when you force it into an int and then back into a short and you get that warning.

Comment: Then why is gcc giving me a warning? error: conversion to ‘short int’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]
The fact of the matter is that it's possible for me to exceed the range of short in this operation, and I would like to catch that.

Comment: @AndreiAndrey: Every multiplication (and most other operators) are done in `int` **at least**. See integer promotions. Of course `s * 2` yields an `int` result!

Comment: @Enno: gcc is correct. Although the warnings for the compound assignment are a bit annoying (they are close to useless for smaller types with that warning enabled if you take warnings as errors), the warnings are justified. I assume MSVC++ is a bit more "forgiving" - for the bad of code quality.

Comment: If you get more warnings, what will you do with them? If you don't want to ignore them, you can either stop using `short` or you can add a bunch of casts to quiet the compiler. The underlying issue, as you mention in your comment, is **not** the "narrowing conversion", but the possibility that the result of the calculation is too large to store in a `short`. Warnings won't fix that problem; analysis and design will.

Comment: @Enno  As for the case with the return statement then "160) The return statement is not an assignment". As for the compound assignment then it is usually assumed an explicit cast to the left operand.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Please provide a reference to the standard about the cast for the compound assignment and the `return`.

Comment: @Olaf I provided a footnote from the C Standard. As for the implied explicit casting then it is usually implemented in such languages as C# and Java.

Comment: @PeteBecker "If you get more warnings, what will you do with them?" Have the code deal with them appropriately, of course. How to do that depends on the actual code in question. If the compiler can point out a mistake like this (as written, all three functions are bad), rather than a code reviewer, then that's a great labor-saving device.

Comment: @Olaf: I agree that gcc's behavior is better, and my question could be phrased as "why doesn't Visual C++ do it this way?" because it would help us avoid those warnings if it did.

Comment: @Enno -- no, the three functions as written are not inherently "bad". If they are never called with values that will result in an overflow they'll work just fine. That's why I said that the solution is analysis and design; you have to understand the limitations of those functions and use them appropriately.

Comment: @Enno: That is the actual question, yes. And it should be asked to the developer, not here. As general advice: gcc is known to have pretty good static code analysis features. As you iriginally tagged C: it is also compliant to standard C and C99, which both MSVC never was.

Comment: If the warning were applied to the situations you're asking about, then pretty much any expression assigned to an integer type smaller than an `int` that was more complex than than just another variable of that type (or smaller) would get the warning.  I suppose MS thought that would be far too noisy (too many false positives) than the warning already is. I suppose that they consider if the expression involves only types that are within the target type's range, then no warning should be issued.